# Why does require('react') cause "Import declaration conflicts" with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsd

I am trying to use Typescript with [`tsd`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) (haven't upgraded to [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings) yet), React, and JSX together... oh my! Talk about build system intricacies...

My `.tsx` file (Typescript + JSX) compiles fine (using `gulp-typescript`) when I use `import * as React from 'react'`. I get an error, however, when I use a `require` statement:

```
./typings/react/react-global.d.ts(17,1): error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts 
with local declaration of 'React'
```

I wouldn't have been surprised if I just imported it wrong and there is some difference between old `require` and new `import` that I haven't grokked yet, but I thought the particular type conflict error I got was strange.

**Just so I understand how imports interact with global tsd declarations better, why does the `require` statement cause an error here?**

Here is my `index.tsx`:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

const config = require('../config')
const express = require('express')
const reactDomServer = require('react-dom/server')
const app = express()

// THIS WORKS
import * as React from 'react'

// THIS DOES NOT
//const React = require('react')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const element = <h1>Hello Denver!</h1>
  res.send(reactDomServer.renderToString(element))
})

const server = app.listen(process.env.port || config.port, () =>
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${server.address().port}!`)
)
```

Here is my `../typings/tsd.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="react-router/history.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react-router/react-router.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-create-fragment.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-css-transition-group.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-linked-state-mixin.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-perf.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-pure-render-mixin.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-test-utils.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-transition-group.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-update.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-dom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-global.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="mime/mime.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="serve-static/serve-static.d.ts" />
```

Comment: If you are using globals you don't need to `import` or `require` anything. If you are using modules then you shouldn't use global references.

Comment: What you said makes sense. If I remove the import or require, however, I get a `"React" undefined` error. It appears that it does require some kind of import.

Comment: Are you including react in a `<script>` tag somehere?

Comment: No, this is server-side.

Comment: Then you don't need the `///` references to React, you just need to import React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> react-global.d.ts

Don't install react global. I am glad to see you already using modules (more https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/tips/outFile.md) so use install react as `typings install dt~react --save` which will install the module react which you can then `import * as React from "react";`